# MariaDB: Terminate long-running clearnup process?

Tags: mariadb, drop-table, kill

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/325259/mariadb-large-insert-select-query-failed-without-generating-an-error) about a long-running `INSERT SELECT` query that may have exceeded the `max_statement_time` and was `Killed`. It has been in the `Reset for next command` state for 3.5 days. I think it is rolling back changes on the table I was inserting into.

However, that table was empty to begin with, and I would rather terminate this cleanup process, drop the table, and start fresh than continue waiting for it to finish. But I do not know if that would be safe for the general health of the database.

The table that I was copying into had no keys, and thus no foreign_key constraints. It was a bare table that I was planning to index once populated.

What is the quickest way for me to get back to work without doing more harm?

```
   Id   User         Host           db Command    Time                   State
10237   root    localhost   singlecell  Killed  300819  Reset for next command
```

Comment: I ended up rebooting the server. That cleared that process and then I was able to drop the table. All seems fine so far...

Comment: `show engine innodb status` might have given some clue what it was doing. With [10.7+](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-innodb-bulk-insert/) doing fast loading I suspect there might be a way to make the rollback quicker. Consider raising a [feature request task](https://jira.mariadb.org).